# Possesive with "between"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, possessives

I'm a bit stuck here. Since **your** and **my** are followed by a noun and **yours** and **mine** are not, the following sentences should be:

- I'm standing between your and my car.

But this seems really wrong. Yet, with **yours** and **mine** it reads better but it's wrong too:

- I'm standing between yours and mine car.

I know that we can say:

- I'm standing between my car and yours (or "your car and mine")

But I'd like it to be like this sentence:

- There are his and her clothes in the wardrobe.

Edit: With **his and her** i can see two meanings:

1. Clothes that belong to him and her alike.
2. Clothes that belong to him and clothes that belong to her.

Comment: what's wrong with the first variant? it's just ellipsis.

Comment: @MvLog I'm not sure if it's correct. It sound odd and really unnatural to me.

Comment: I think sentences such as the one you would "like it to be" are avoided by native speakers in favor of other constructions.   *The wardrobe contains clothing of his and clothing of hers.*  *The both of them have clothes in the wardrobe.* *The wardrobe contains clothing of the both of them.*  *The wardrobe contains clothing of hers and clothing of her sister.*

Comment: There's nothing wrong with 'your and my car', but it's uncommon English. The 'commoner' English would be 'our car'.

Comment: @user178049 I can't see how "**your and my car**" changes to "**our car**". It's two different cars we are talking about. One belongs to you and the other one to me.

Comment: @SovereignSun In that case, you would say 'your and my car**s**' as explained by smatterer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could say: “I'm standing between your and my car**s**.” Note that there are two car**s**. “Your and my car” means it is one shared car.

It probably sounds better to say “I'm standing between your car and mine.”

You are right that “There are his and her clothes in the wardrobe.” is ambiguous and it also sounds awkward.  A better alternative would be: “There are his clothes and hers in the wardrobe.”

Note that the English idiom “his and hers” refers to matching male and female items.